# Converting CIImage to CGImage too slow

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, cgimage, ciimage

I need to convert a `CIImage` to a `CGImage`. This is the code I am currently using:

```
CGImageRef img = [myContext createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];
```

But his line of code is very slow for images with a regular size. Much to slow that I can use it properly. Is there another faster method to convert these `CIImages` to `CGImages`?

In the end I use `Core Graphics` to draw the `CGImages` to a `CGContext`. If there is a way to directly draw `CIImages` to a `CGContext` i think that should also be faster. Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [CIImage documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/index.html):

> Although a CIImage object has image data associated with it, it is not
>   an image. You can think of a CIImage object as an image “recipe.” A
>   CIImage object has all the information necessary to produce an image,
>   but Core Image doesn’t actually render an image until it is told to do
>   so. This “lazy evaluation” method allows Core Image to operate as
>   efficiently as possible.

This means that any filtering you may have applied (or better *requested to apply*) to your `CIImage` won't actually occur until you render the image, which in your case happens when you create the `CGImageRef`. That's probably the reason you're experiencing the slow down.

That said, filtering on `CIImage` is generally a really fast process so based on your image size you should give us your definition of slow.

Finally to make sure the bottleneck is really where you think it is you should [profile your application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) by using Instruments.

**Edit**

I've just tried building a sample project that filters an image stream coming from the device camera (960x540) on an iPad3 by applying the `CIColorMap` color filter and I'm getting over 60fps (~16ms).

Depending on your application you'll get better performances by reusing the `CIContext`, the `ColorMapFilter`, the `inputGradientImage` (if it doesn't change over time) and updating only the `inputImage` on every iteration.

For example you would call `prepareFrameFiltering` once and then repeatably call `applyFilterToFrame:` on every frame you want to process.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CIContext *context;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CIFilter *colorMapFilter;

- (void)prepareFrameFiltering {
    self.context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *colorMap = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.jpg"].CGImage];
    self.colorMapFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMap"];
    [self.colorMapFilter setValue:colorMap forKey:@"inputGradientImage"];
}

- (void)applyFilterToFrame:(CIImage *)ciFrame {    
    // filter
    [self.colorMapFilter setValue:ciFrame forKey:@"inputImage"];
    CIImage *ciImageResult = [self.colorMapFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

    CGImageRef ref = [self.context createCGImage:ciImageResult fromRect:ciFrame.extent];

    // do whatever you need

    CGImageRelease(ref);
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. I did not know that. So then I guess that actually the CIFilter I am using is so slow. I am using a ColorMap filter. For a 600x800 picture it needs about 1 sec to render it to a CGImage. Which is a bit too much for me as I am doing this many times in a row. In any case, thank you for your answer. I learned something. And if you have an idea how to speed up this process pls tell me.

Comment: sry forgot to mention, this was on my macbook pro in the iossimulator. On the actual device its even worse

Comment: That's weird as I would expect that CIColorMap should be performed on the GPU and therefore fast. I'll check it out myself later. In the meantime what device did you use?

Comment: i have an old ipad 2 on which i run this

Comment: Using the GPU on Simulator is actually quite slow - in fact it is slower than using GPU on an actual iOS device.  The CIColorMap filter is actually quite simple just a bit of math and a lookup in the gradient image.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to render a CIImage is to render into a EAGLContext.

Rendering a CIImage into a CGContext is not as performant because CI works on the GPU but CG is a CPU renderer.  CI must read its results back from the GPU to the CPU so that CG can render it.

Note: This read-back will happen when createCGImage: is called if the image is smaller than 4K.  It will happen when CGContextDrawImage is called if the image is larger.

Comment: Hi, can u provide some examples? As I know you are trying to tell us to using `CIContext render`... instead of `CIContext createCGImage`